# Condition of touching in second degree curves

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Let there be two curves $S:(x-\sqrt{7})^2+y^2=R^2$ and $S':\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{y^2}{9}=1$, then what is the value of $R$ such that $S$ and $S'$ touch at exactly one point?

---

substituting $y^2$ from $S$ into $S'$ we get $$\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{R^2-(x-\sqrt{7})^2}{9}=1$$

$$\frac{1}{144}(  7 x^2 - 32 \sqrt{7} x  +256-16R^2)=0$$

Now since the curves should only touch at exactly one point, the discriminant of this quadratic must be $0$,

$$\Delta=\left(32\sqrt{7}\right)^{2}-4\cdot7\cdot\left(256-16R^{2}\right)=0\implies R=0$$
but this is wrong as the given answer is $R=4\pm \sqrt{7}$ which is true

[image]

[image]

So why is discriminant equals zero not giving the right answer here?

Comment: Notice that $y^2$ is always positive , meaning, x is bounded with  parameter R, hence, You cannot comment on discriminant of complete quadratic, as S and S' touch at only point, You can only deduce that, The quadratic has only one root in above bounded range of x

Comment: There is another way to attack this problem. You know that you can draw a common tangent to two curves at their point of touching.  Therefore, you can try to find the points at which the slopes of the individual curves have the same value. If you do this, you will see that at the two points $y=0$ and $x=\dfrac{16}{\sqrt{7}}$ the two given curves $S$ and $S’$ have the same slopes. However, only one of them gives points lying on the curve $S’$.

Comment: The fundamental reason is that the symmetry $y\leftrightarrow -y$ means your substitution of $y^2$ collapses the pair of intersection points $(x,\pm y)$ back down to one ($x$) and in our case when there are only two intersection points (technically counted with multiplicity) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you will have to pick up the other pair of non-real intersection points (recall there are 4 points of intersection over $\mathbb{C}$) as the other root of the quadratic.  So equating discriminant to zero does not have the effect you think it should have here.

Answer (score 2):

The circle is centered at a point (focus of the ellipse) lying on the major axis of the ellipse, which is horizontal. The unique common point of the two curves lies necessarily on the same line. Therefore, $y=0.$
Uploading into $S'$ gives
$$x^2=16\quad \text{or}\quad x=\pm 4.$$
Substituting into $S$ we get
$$(\pm 4-\sqrt7)^2+0^2=R^2$$
or equivalently
$$R=4\pm \sqrt7$$